# Arrange graphics in a 2x2 layout sideways

Tags: graphics

I have a quick question. I like to display four plots sideways in a grid. So far I managed to put in two plots next to each other. I'm snuggling a little bit to align my plots in a 2x2 layout. Is there a quick way to do that ?

cheers

```
\usepackage{rotating}
...  
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{plot1.png}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{plot2.png} 
    \caption{My plots in a grid}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Comment: just use a blank line then two more images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not tabular?

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{plot1.png} & 
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{plot2.png} \\
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{plot2.png} & 
        \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{plot4.png} 
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
    \caption{My plots in a grid}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tabular` with two centered columns. You can use 
`\tabcolsep` to control the interimage space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.0mm}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{plot1.png}&\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{plot2.png}\\
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{plot1.png}&\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{plot2.png} 
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My plots in a grid}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```